# Swype delete key problem

Tags: email, swype

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with the latest firmware an a preinstalled Swype on it.

The problem I have, is in the standard email application when using swype keyboard and trying to delete a character, it will append the word again and so it's impossible to delete a word. For example: I type `Test`, then hit the backspace button and it results in `TesTest`.

My question is now, can I solve this problem without having to root the phone in order to reinstall swype?

---

Addition: My android version is 2.3.5, my firware version I9100BOKJ1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ICS rom installed? I have that same issue with T9 keyboard on the Galaxy Nexus. I reported the issue to Nuance but they claimed the T9 doesn't support ICS.

You can fix it by holding down the backspace key until the whole field is cleared, then switch to a non-sliding keyboard to enter the info in the `To:` field.

Comment: This is good information, but I would guess that the OP doesn't have ICS installed since the question does ask: `can I solve this problem without having to root the phone` (implying a currently unrooted phone).

Comment: @eldarerathis: That's right. I have added some info above.

Comment: @gadzooks64: See info above. You are right, I can delete the whole word by holding backspace long enough (which is very long).